# How can i add cc and bcc emails in order email using opencart 2.1?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add cc and bcc emails when order process using opencart 2.1. I know i can add additional emails through Settings > Mail > Addition Alert Emails. But I need in cc and bcc. I would like appreciate if someone guide me about this.

Comment: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15894

Comment: @zod Thanks for suggestion... I want to do myself

Comment: you mean additional_headers  of  mail() http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php .. it may be using  in opencart internally

Comment: @zod yes i want additional email, let me check in files

Answer (score 0):

From the admin panel
system->settings->mail
In the last option you can add extra notification emails.